# How to refactor following function to reduce duplication? Slick, Pattern Matching, Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

Anyone know how I can reduce duplication in the patterning matching statement in the following function? specifically i want to generalize the if statement. I'm thinking if I could somehow pass the object properties into a function then I could do it, but I have no idea how. Any help is MUCH APPRECIATED. THANKS!!

```
 Ex: if (ASC) _.uid.asc else _.uid.desc
```

Below is the function

```
  /**
   * Finds all the users and sorts by column ascending or descending. Ascending or Descending is determined by
   * if the orderBy value is positive or negative. These values are held in constants  in @package models.AdminPage
   * @param orderBy The column to be sorted.
   * @return a list of sorted users.
   */
   def findAll(orderBy: Int = DefaultSortByUid) =  DB.withSession {
     implicit s: Session =>
       val q = for(u <- User) yield u

       // Get the absolute value to determine the column to be sorted. A valid value will be an Int that corresponds
       // to one of the constants defined in @package models.AdminPage.
       val sortByColumn = orderBy.abs
       val ASC = orderBy > 0

       val users = q.sortBy(sortByColumn match  {
         case `SortByUid` => if (ASC) _.uid.asc else _.uid.desc
         case `SortByUserName` => if(ASC) _.userId.asc else _.userId.desc
         case `SortByAuthMethod` => if(ASC) _.authMethod.asc  else _.authMethod.desc
         case `SortByRole` =>  if(ASC) _.role.asc else _.role.desc
         case `SortByEmail` => if(ASC) _.email.asc else _.email.desc
         case `SortByFirstName` => if(ASC) _.firstName.asc else _.firstName.desc
         case `SortByLastName` => if(ASC) _.lastName.asc else  _.lastName.desc
         //An invalid value just goes to table main page and to default sort of ascending by uid
         case _ => _.uid.asc
       }).list

       users
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the column objects share a common parent on which .desc and .asc are available
If so, you make an helper function:

```
def orderBy(direction, column) {
    if (direction) column.asc else column.desc
}
```

and invoke it like so in each of the cases:

```
case ... => orderBy(ASC, _.uid)
```

Or even better reverse it and make de match return _.uid and use it as input for orderBy

Comment: Yeah thats what I've been trying to do but I have no idea what type _.uid is and how to pass it into a function. Thats where I'm stuck.

Comment: @danielh It looks like you already figured out the type to be Column[T]

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can do. Can anyone do better?

```
 /**
  * Find all users and sort by column, ascending or descending.
  *
  * @param orderBy Column to be sorted.
  * @return Sorted list of users.
  */
   def findAll(orderBy: Int = DefaultSortByUid) =  DB.withSession {
    implicit s: Session =>
    val q = for(u <- User) yield u

  // Ascending or Descending is determined by the sign of orderBy.
  def sort[T] (column: Column[T]) = if (orderBy > 0) column.asc else column.desc

  // Case values are defined as constants in @class models.AdminPage
  q.sortBy(c => sort( orderBy.abs match  {
    case `SortByUserName` =>  c.userId
    case `SortByAuthMethod` => c.authMethod
    case `SortByRole` =>  c.role
    case `SortByEmail` => c.email
    case `SortByFirstName` => c.firstName
    case `SortByLastName` =>  c.lastName
    case _ => c.uid
  })).list
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you are looking for:

```
/** Find all users and sort by column, ascending or descending.
  *
  * @param column  Column to be sorted.
  * @param asc     Sort ascending.
  * @return        Sorted list of users.
  */
def findAll[T <% Ordered](column: User => T = _.uid, asc: Boolean = true) = DB withSession {
  def sort(r: Records) = if (asc) column(r).asc else column(r).desc
  val q = for(u <- User) yield u
  q.sortBy(sort).list
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
val usersByEmailDesc = findAll(_.email, asc = false)
```

Please let me know if this is does it for you -- the next step is to make a generator to generalize this, so that it's one line to add it to each new table.

Comment: @ms-ati Do not ask for an 'accept' in an answer. Let alone ask for an accept in someone else their answer.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I find your officious tone unhelpful. Please restore what you consider the acceptable portions of my edit and we can discuss. Otherwise, please delight in removing useful information.